# how to use delete statement with subqueries - error 1093?

Tags: mysql

This query returns exactly the office tuples I need to delete.

```
    SELECT id, reference FROM office o 
WHERE o.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT c.office_id FROM Contract c  WHERE office_id IS NOT NULL)
AND o.reference IN 
    (SELECT o.reference FROM Contract c JOIN office o ON c.office_id = o.id  WHERE office_id IS NOT NULL);
```

But when I write the query

```
    DELETE FROM office 
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT c.office_id FROM Contract c  WHERE office_id IS NOT NULL)
AND reference IN 
    (SELECT o.reference FROM Contract c JOIN office o ON c.office_id = o.id  WHERE office_id IS NOT NULL);
```

I have the following error : `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'office' for update in FROM clause`

But I really don't see how to solve this..

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 DELETE FROM office 
 WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT c.office_id FROM Contract c
 WHERE office_id IS NOT NULL)
 AND reference IN 
(select * from (SELECT o.reference FROM Contract c 
 JOIN office o ON c.office_id = o.id 
 WHERE office_id   IS NOT NULL) x);
```

since you can't delete from a table where you are selecting from. But using

```
select * from (select col from your_table) x
```

should do the trick

Comment: (thanks for answering) With your query, I have now the following error : #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Sure. Sorry, forgot that. I just updated the answer. YOu have to name every sub query with a name